# Struggling with xslt grouping and querying against xpath count

Tags: xslt-1.0

So I'm stuck with XSLT 1.0

In my XML I have something like this:

```
    <BenefitDefinitions>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>Test</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>Test</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>C</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>Test</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
    </BenefitDefinitions>
...
    <Coverage>
      <Cover>
        <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
      <Cover>
    </Coverage>
```

The logic needs to be where there are multiple benefit Definitions that have that same fulfillmentName - I need to check if any of them exist as a cover.  With the linkage between the two being the BenefitCode.

I tried using a key to get the benefitDefinitions into groups based on the fulfillment name

```
  <xsl:key name="benefits-by-fulfillmentname" match="BenefitDefinition" use="FulfillmentName/text()" />
```

and I can iterate through the groups where there is more than 1

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//BenefitDefinition[count(. | key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName/text())[1]) = 1]">
```

I could also iterate through the benefitDefinitions of that group by:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName/text())">
```

But what I can't figure out is how I can make use of the key to get a count.

I want something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../../../../Contract/Risks/PersonContractRisk[RiskId = $riskId]/Coverage/Cover[BenefitCode=key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', BenefitCode)])"/>
```

But that's not working - I'm not skilled with xslt so not too surprising.

All my searching just tells me how to count the benefitDefinitions that belong in that group.. but I need to go more advanced and find out how many covers exist for that benefitDefinition group.

Pretty much where I want to go to (in case this helps) is for each benefitDefinition group if there is a cover output 1 thing, otherwise output something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to count or iterate; a simple existence test will suffice.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="benefits-by-fulfillmentname" match="BenefitDefinition" use="FulfillmentName" />
<xsl:key name="cover-by-benefitcode" match="Cover" use="BenefitCode" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/BenefitDefinitions/BenefitDefinition[count(. | key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName)[1]) = 1]">
            <group name="{FulfillmentName}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="key('cover-by-benefitcode', key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName)/BenefitCode)">
                        <xsl:text>there is a cover</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>there is not</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the following **valid** XML test input:

```
<root>
    <BenefitDefinitions>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group A</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group A</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>C</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group A</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>C</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group B</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
    </BenefitDefinitions>

    <Coverage>
      <Cover>
        <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
      </Cover>
    </Coverage>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <group name="group A">there is a cover</group>
  <group name="group B">there is not</group>
</output>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks will give that a go.  I had no idea how to test that existence (but that's what I wanted). :)

Comment: If this problem was complicated so that you had a list of risks, and they each had their own list of covers - how would you filter the cover-by-benefitcode to be restricted based on a riskId?

Comment: @Jen Sorry, I am afraid I don't follow. Perhaps you should post a new question and include the relevant code?

Comment: Sure - I didn't want to edit this question so I'll post another with more details.  I missed this detail when trying to extract the important bits out of our system which might be sensitive :)