# Checking existence - multiple keys in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

So I have this xml

```
<BenefitDefinitions>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>Test</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>Test</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>C</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>Test</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
    </BenefitDefinitions>
...
    <Risks>
      <ContractRisk>
        <RiskId>1</RiskId>
          <Coverage>
            <Cover>
               <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
            <Cover>
          </Coverage>
      </ContractRisk>
      <ContractRisk>
        <RiskId>2</RiskId>
          <Coverage>
            <Cover>
               <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
            <Cover>
          </Coverage>
      </ContractRisk>
     </Risks>
```

I need to apply a transformation to this where basically:

```
For each risk 
  For each benefit definition group (where a group has the same fulfillmentName)
    If the benefit group has a cover associated to it (matched on benefitCode) 
          display the cover details
    Otherwise 
         display not covered details
```

Stuck with using xslt 1.0 but I don't fully get the concept of keys and how to filter keys.. So I know if I didn't have covers by risk I could use something like this:

```
<xsl:key name="benefits-by-fulfillmentname" match="BenefitDefinition" use="FulfillmentName/text()" />
  <xsl:key name="cover-by-benefitcode" match="Cover" use="BenefitCode" />

  <!-- TODO: Make BonusSumInsured read from correct extract data when available -->
  <xsl:template name="PolicyScheduleBenefits">
    <xsl:param name="riskId" select="../../RiskId"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="//BenefitDefinition[count(. | key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName/text())[1]) = 1]">

        <group name="{FulfillmentName}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="key('cover-by-benefitcode', key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName)/BenefitCode)">
              <xsl:text>there is a cover</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:text>there is not</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </group>
```

But I'm not sure how to adapt this to check for the existence of covers per risk.

Comment: Just to clarify: if there were 2 risks and 3 benefit definition groups, the result would have 2 subsections (one per risk) with each subsection listing all 3 groups; IOW, each group needs to appear several times in the result - is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct @michael.hor257k  It's basically being used to drive mail packs, so we need to generate letters for each person as to what cover they have or not. The reason we need to group is when the benefit definitions have the same fulfilment name, we don't want to ouput 3 times that they're not covered, we just want to do it once. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am afraid that's still not entirely clear. Your XML is not a varied enough example (not to mention invalid...). Can a ContractRisk have multiple BenefitCodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you 'cover-by-benefitcode' key looks up 'cover' for all risks, but you only want to check it for a specific risk.

To solve this, just add a condition to check the risk after your current use of the key, like so:

```
<xsl:when test="key('cover-by-benefitcode', key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName)/BenefitCode)
                [../../RiskId =$riskId]">
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I would do it this way: assuming this is a representative example of your XML input:

```
<root>
   <BenefitDefinitions>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>A</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group ABC</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group ABC</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>C</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group ABC</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group BD</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
      <BenefitDefinition>
         <BenefitCode>D</BenefitCode>
         <FulfillmentName>group BD</FulfillmentName>
      </BenefitDefinition>
   </BenefitDefinitions>
   <Risks>
      <ContractRisk>
         <RiskId>BC</RiskId>
         <Coverage>
            <Cover>
               <BenefitCode>B</BenefitCode>
            </Cover>
            <Cover>
               <BenefitCode>C</BenefitCode>
            </Cover>
         </Coverage>
      </ContractRisk>
      <ContractRisk>
         <RiskId>D</RiskId>
         <Coverage>
            <Cover>
               <BenefitCode>D</BenefitCode>
            </Cover>
         </Coverage>
      </ContractRisk>
   </Risks>
</root>
```

then this stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="benefits-by-fulfillmentname" match="BenefitDefinition" use="FulfillmentName" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <risks>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/Risks/ContractRisk">
            <risk id="{RiskId}">
            <xsl:variable name="riskCodes" select="Coverage/Cover/BenefitCode" />
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/BenefitDefinitions/BenefitDefinition[count(. | key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName)[1]) = 1]">
                    <group name="{FulfillmentName}">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="key('benefits-by-fulfillmentname', FulfillmentName)/BenefitCode=$riskCodes">
                                <xsl:text>there is a cover</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:text>there is not</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </group>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </risk>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </risks> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<risks>
   <risk id="BC">
      <group name="group ABC">there is a cover</group>
      <group name="group BD">there is a cover</group>
   </risk>
   <risk id="D">
      <group name="group ABC">there is not</group>
      <group name="group BD">there is a cover</group>
   </risk>
</risks>
```

--
Note: unlike your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863664/struggling-with-xslt-grouping-and-querying-against-xpath-count), this is no longer an "existence test", but a node-set comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer (again).  I was finding that this
<xsl:variable name="riskCodes" select="../../Coverage/Cover/BenefitCode" />
has no value (when adding it to a watch) as it sits on the same level as RiskId in my xml.  I also tried //Coverage/Cover/BenefitCode which wouldn't work if there were multiple risks.  And that also didn't populate the variable with anything.  But adding a watch of "//Coverage/Cover/BenefitCode" gave me a nodeset of 2 dimensions.  The other post did the trick though.

Comment: @Jen I am afraid I don't understand your comment. The $riskCodes variable needs to be populated while you are still in the context of Risk, and it needs to be populated by the BenefitCodes that are descendants of the current risk. That's how it works in my answer - don't know why it wouldn't work for you. Regarding Tim's suggestion, that would (eventually) work too; I just don't like the mixture of key with predicates - I believe it's an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I totally get that it needs to be populated - but in working with that code (and playing around with the path I couldn't see any value when I added it as a watch :( ).  No idea why it wasn't working when I used the same path as another watch.